# Azure Redis Cache Timeout and No Connection error

Tags: caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

I keep getting these errors related to Azure Redis once in a while from my API web app on Azure

```
Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 1, queue: 2, qu: 0, qs: 2, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: RD00155DD0C827, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=1022,Min=1,Max=1023), Local-CPU: unavailable
```

No connection:

```
No connection is available to service this operation: EVALUnableToConnect on ausession.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, origin: ResetNonConnected, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 13s ago, last-write: 13s ago, unanswered-write: 180447s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 13s ago
```

I am using **Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis v1.1.1** in my ASP.net project. 
Redis Configuration:

```
ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=10000
```

I am using Azure Redis size **C1 Standard** (1GB) and have it configured as below (setting maxmemory-reserved and maxfragmentationmemory-reserved to 50)

https://gyazo.com/9d14a317cf23e9e64a31b80ad7d061a3

Do you know what cause the error and how to stop it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts can be a result of many things, including high server load, expensive commands being executed, high client side CPU, poorly configured client threadpool, etc.  Here are some articles that talk about each of the most common causes of Timeouts:

[Diagnosing Server issues](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/9225f783a40564c9879d#file-diagnoserediserrors-serverside-md)
[Diagnosing Client issues](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md)

As for the connection related issues, those can be caused by several things, including server side scaling, failover or patching, client side scaling or deployment, client side or server side network driver updates, etc.  Below is an article that talks about some of these

https://gist.github.com/JonCole/317fe03805d5802e31cfa37e646e419d#file-azureredis-patchingexplained-md

Lastly, I have a set of [Best Practices](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#file-redis-bestpractices-general-md) that I have gathered as a result of helping hundreds of customers diagnose these types of issues and you may want to read through that as well.

If you still can't figure it out, contact customer support and they can help out.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is the StackExchange.Redis nuget package different from Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis? Should I change to use the former?

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis wraps StackExchange.Redis

Answer (score 0):

I removed `<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">`
from web.config file and it fixed it.